# Google chose different canonical than user

Tags: indexing, seo, single-page-application, search-engine, google-search-console

Recently my domain lost too many indexed URLs.
when I checked the search console report, there are more than 1000 URLs with this error:

`Page is not indexed: Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user`

When I checked each url inspection report, there is something like this:

```
User-declared canonical: www.domain.com/articles/123  
Google-selected canonical: www.domain.com/articles/789
```

there is no relation between these two articles' ids !!

what can I do to solve this problem and get links to show up in the search again?

my website is SPA, using AngularJs

Comment: Sometimes it is a rendering issue. Do a live test on each URL and look at the snapshot. Do you see the content?